# How do I get all related rows from a third relationship table in Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

I have three tables, `experiences`, `images` and `experience_images`.

In `experience_images` I have two columns, `experience_id` and `image_id`. This table can hold many images for one experience, something like this:

```
"experience_id","image_id"
"6","31"
"6","32"
"6","33"
"6","34"
```

Now how do I get a collection of `Image` from my `Experience` model by running `Experience::find(6)->images`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set up the relationship in your Eloquent model

```
class Experience extends Eloquent {
    public function images(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Image', 'experience_images', 'experience_id', 'image_id');
    }
}
```

[In the Official Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many)

Comment: @Marwelln Are those implicit foreign keys really necessary? Normally you could leave them and by convention it takes the lowercase model name + '_id'

Comment: In my case it is as both my models are named `Model`, but I guess it could have been skipped as the models in your example is named `Experience` and `Image`. You can revert my edit if you would like to.

Comment: Ahh ok, i assumed you had the conventional model names

Comment: I have it namespaced `App\Models\Experience\Model`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an id in the paremeter find(). In this case is 6:

```
$exp = Experience::find(6);

foreach($exp->images as $e){

       return $e->somedata;

}
```